# convert from sort of long format to one row expanded

Tags: r, data.table

Trying to convert some tab data into one expanded row where the names are formed from the column names joined to the values of a "by" column... in a compact/elegant manner...

Easier with a MWE, which uses data.table but can be whatever (although data.table preferred):

```
library(data.table)
# input
bar <- data.table(c1 = c(1L, 2L), c2 = c(3L, 4L), c3 = c("aa", "bb"))
# output
baz <- data.table(c1_aa = 1L, c1_bb = 2L, c2_aa = 3L, c3_bb = 4L)
```

So input is:

```
> bar
   c1 c2 c3
1:  1  3 aa
2:  2  4 bb
```

and desired output is:

```
> baz
   c1_aa c1_bb c2_aa c3_bb
1:     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: Pretty sure efficiency cannot matter for something like this unless your final output has hundreds of thousands of columns. Anyway, there's `dcast(melt(bar, id="c3"), . ~ variable + c3)` analogous to useR's answer.

Comment: @Frank ditto! efficiency meaning more as compact as possible... and this will do. many thanks. post if you can and will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the data.table analogue of @useR's answer

```
dcast(melt(bar, id="c3"), . ~ variable + c3)
```

It happens to be short thanks to `dcast` defaults (on column ordering and use of `_` as separator).

Comment: thanks, noticed that it creates one column "."... so easily fixed with a `[, -1, with = F]` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Not `data.table`, but works great with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bar %>%
  gather(variable, value, c1:c2) %>%
  unite(variable, variable, c3, sep = "_") %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```

**Result:**

```
  c1_aa c1_bb c2_aa c2_bb
1     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: many thanks. nice answer and upvoted... sligthly prefer Frank's answer above only because in a minimal package policy...

Comment: @JohnSmith You can treat `tidyverse` as one package :)